# What is the correct way to use a vertexArray in sfml?

Tags: c++, sfml

After doing some research it would appear that using vertexArrays in the most efficientways of drawing many sprites onto the screen at once but I'm struggling how to do it. I've attempted using the sfml forums but every example I've seen has been from outdated code  I have this so far.

```
int main() 
{
    sf::VertexArray lines(sf::LinesStrip, 4);
    lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0, 0),sf::Vector2f(0, 0)));
    lines.append(sf::Vector2f(0, 50));
    lines.append(sf::Vector2f(250, 50));
    lines.append(sf::Vector2f(250, 0));

    sf::Texture text;
    text.loadFromFile("Content/StartGame.png");

    sf::RenderStates rend(&text);

    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Graphics");

    // Start game loop
    while (App.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.close();
        }
        App.clear();
        App.draw(lines, &text);
        App.display();
    }
}
```

I have the shape drawing but when I attempt to apply to the texture too it, nothing draws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use like this:

```
 sf::VertexArray lines(sf::LinesStrip, 4);
 lines[0].position = sf::Vector2f(10, 0);
 lines[1].position = sf::Vector2f(20, 0);
 lines[2].position = sf::Vector2f(30, 5);
 lines[3].position = sf::Vector2f(40, 2);

 window.draw(lines);
```

Comment: How would the texture ever be applied too it?

Comment: The vertex class has the class member texCoords which you can use to designate the texture `lines[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(x,y);`

Answer (score 2):

You are not supplying any texture coordinates when you are constructing sf::Vector2f; pass in some texture coordinates as the third parameter, like:

```
lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0, 0),sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Vector2f(0,0)));
```

The texture coordinates should be something like `0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0`, and `1,1`.

You might also have to change your shape type to `sf::Quads` (it's been a while since I've used SFML, so this may or may not be true).

Comment: `code`

 sf::VertexArray lines(sf::Quads, 4);
    lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0, 0),sf::Vector2f(0, 0)));
 lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0, 50),sf::Vector2f(0, 50)));
 lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(250, 50),sf::Vector2f(250, 50)));
 lines.append(sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(250, 0),sf::Vector2f(250, 0)));

applied some commonsense and managed to get it too work. Now to learn how to apply this code to make things draw more efficient ways.